# Create Function Gas Fees to have a Dynamic Fees based on Gas Fees

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, fees

is it possible in solidity create a function to estimate a gas fee and apply a % of fees based on gas fees ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The smart contract can't handle the gas fee because the gas fee is determined by the market demand and node validators so you can do it using RPC services with ethers.js or web3.js.

Getting in inside a smart contract will generate a need for oracles.